В какой компонент лучше записать список заданий в WindowsForm?
Есть форма на которой у меня по центру ComboBox и там написан список  Задания 1..Задания 4й. Далее при выборе определенного задания, например Задания 1 (вывести название ресторанов) и результат этого задания будет выведено в DataGridView. Так вот как можно красиво вывести список заданий, если я пихаю задания в ComboBox то там они могут не поместится т.к слишком длинные. Что можете предложить ?
СКРИНШОТ ФОРМЫ ГДЕ Я ВЫБИРАЮ, В ComboBox Задание 1 и у по этому заданию в DataGridView выводяся значения, а нужно что бы вместо задание 1 было как-то красиво вот это задание:
Вывести номер публикации, название публикации, название издательства, фамилии  авторов, цену, дату издания. Список упорядочить по номеру публикации  по алфавиту.


А вам обязательно нужно чтобы целиком длинные строки выводились при выборе? Обычно их как-то обрезают для выбора из списка.

Ну что бы красво задания выводились

можно в любом, какой больше нравится, переопределить template и у элемента отображения текста поставить TextWrapping="Wrap" -  всё поместится, но выглядеть будет крайне убого, на мой взгляд

Покажите скриншот как это сейчас выглядит. Я бы тупо обрезал названия по какой-то длине. Наверняка там и параметры какие-то на эту тему есть, как обрезать. Ну или просто ширину контрола выставить, тогда будет наверное по ширине только показываться что уместится.

@CrazyElf добавил!

Ну сделайте комбобокс на всю ширину окна, что она у вас зря пропадает то. И напишите там "Задание 1: Вывести номер публикации..." обрежется оно наверное само по заданной вами ширине контрола.

И да, как написали выше, после выбора элемента в комбобоксе ниже него заполняйте лейбл (или текстбокс? не уверен, что лейбл бывает многострочный) и пишите там полный текст задания. Попробуйте разные варианты, смотрите, как лучше будет выглядеть.

@CrazyElf Спасибо за ответ! Я добавил TextBox, далее добавил ему свойство multiline = True и далее когда пользователь выбирает задание 1 в ComboBox то в TextBox заносится описание этого задания.
